# Flask route doesn't capture parts containing urlencoded slash

Tags: python, flask

I have defined a Flask route as follows:

```
@app.route('/upload/from_url/<url:string>')
def upload_from_url(url: str) -> str:
    return {'url': url}
```

I also tried the route with `<url>` only. In any case, the route doesn't match if it contains a URL encoded slash. For example, this fails:

```
https://example.com/upload/from_url/https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com
```

Whereas this one works:

```
https://example.com/upload/from_url/github.com
```

I am confused why Flask would decode the URL before attempting to match, that seems to defeat the purpose of the encoding.

What's the right way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this link partially answers your question:

https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/900

It's said: `This is a limitation in WSGI and there is nothing I can do about that.` [comment](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/900#issuecomment-34558427)

ps: some comments there seem to be helpful or maybe there could be a workaround.

Comment: Indeed. Well, this sucks. Unfortunately the workarounds (double or even triple encoding on client side) don't work if you have no control over the client. Well, I guess I'll have to look for a non-WSGI approach. Urgs. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Yup, I also disagree about double-encoding, it just combine errors together to get a likely-correct result. It really sucks.